# The Dirichlet series of the harmonic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I'm curious about the Dirichlet series $$F(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^s}$$
of the sequence $H_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$  of harmonic numbers.  Its abscissa of convergence is $1$.  What properties does it have?  Does it have analytic continuation?  Does it have a closed-form expression? What is its asymptotic behavior at $s = 1$?  (It diverges there.) Does it satisfy a functional equation?  I can't find any information about it, nor can I answer any of these questions.

Note that
$$F(m) = \frac{m+2}{2}\zeta(m+1)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{m-2} \zeta(m-k)\zeta(k+1)$$
for any integer $m>1$.  That's about all I know.

Oh, and for obvious reasons, $F(s) - 1$ is asymptotic to $\frac{H_2}{2^s}$ as $s \to \infty$.

Comment: if you write $H_n =\log n + \gamma +c_n$ we know that $c_n=O(1/n)$ so $\sum c_n n^{-s}$ has abscissa at most $0$ while of course, we know $\sum \log n /n^s$ etc; similarly we can extend the abscissa by using more asymptotic terms; the asymptotic behavior at $1$ is obviously given by $-\zeta'+\gamma \zeta$ since the remainder series is analytic there

Comment: I believe the singularity at $0$ is a second-order pole (breaking the series into regimes $n\sim 2^k$ and using $H_n\sim\log n$, we obtain something like the differentiated geometric series formula), though I don't see how to transform this into an asymptotic expansion // EDIT: this is clearly a consequence of the previous comment as well

Comment: What motivated this question? The harmonic numbers seem to be a curious choice for coefficients of a Dirichlet series.

Comment: Well, $H_{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ is the summatory function of $\frac{1}{n}$, so $\zeta(s+1) = s \int_1^\infty\frac{H_{\lfloor x \rfloor}}{x^{s+1}}dx$.  I was considering the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{H_{\lfloor x \rfloor}-\log x -\gamma}{x^s}dx$, which equals $G(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}\left(\zeta(s)-\gamma-\frac{1}{s-1}\right)$, and the sum in question, or @Conrad's version (which I had already considered) is a ``discrete integral'' version of that.  Note that $G(1) = -\gamma_1$.

Comment: You can do the same with any function $f(x)$ (e.g., $f(x) = g(x)-h(x)$ where $g(x)\sim h(x)$).  The integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^s}dx$ is something people study, but then, why not also the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^x}$?  Take $f(x) = \operatorname{li}(x)-\pi(x)$ and you already get something interesting.

Comment: By the same token, in another direction, you could also consider the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{H_x-\gamma-\log x}{x^s}dx$, where $H_x = \Psi(x+1) +\gamma$ and $\Psi(x)$ is the digamma function.  Analogous to the original question, one can ask what $\int_1^\infty \frac{H_x}{x^s}dx$ or $\int_1^\infty \frac{\Psi(x+1)}{x^s}dx$ are, and I don't know the answer to that question, either.

Comment: @Conrad : I am now sure how to make [your idea](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457508/the-dirichlet-series-of-the-harmonic-numbers/457511#comment1185039_457508) work. The sums in $n$ of the terms of the expansion of $H_n$ will be $\zeta'(s)$, $\zeta(s)$, $\zeta(s+1)$, $\zeta(s+2)$, $\zeta(s+3)$, etc., with some universal constant coefficients. But these sums are not analytic at $s$ equal $1,1,0,-1,-2,\dots$.

Comment: @JesseElliott : Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: @Iosif yes the function should have poles there so it is meromorphic and more complicated than zeta say in a sense

Comment: @Conrad : According to the [answer below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457511/36721), an extension of $F$ is analytic everywhere except at $1$.

Comment: @Iosif Fix a level $k \ge 1$, then using the asymptotics $H_n=\log n+\gamma + \sum_{1 \le j \le k}c_jn^{-2j} +r_k(n)$ with $r_k(n)=O(n^{-2k})$ we can write $F(s)=-\zeta'(s)+\gamma \zeta(s)+ \sum_{1 \le j \le k}c_j\zeta(s+2j)+R_k(s)$ valid for $\Re s >1$ where $R_k$ is analytic on $\Re s >1-2k$; in particular the RHS is meromorphic on $\Re s >1-2k$ so gives the meromorphic continuation of $F$ there so it seems that there are poles at $1-2j, j \ge 1$; now the coefficients $c_k, r_k(n)$ blow up with $k$, so the representation above is not a series one but valid only for fixed $k$

Comment: @IosifPinelis I didn't respond to it because the answer was too high level, i.e., it made a claim based on a seemingly unrelated example from a paper that is heavy on notation.  If you could say more specifically about how you'd go about addressing question that I asked more directly, then I might be more inclined to accept the answer.  That shouldn't be difficult for you to do since you wrote the paper.

Comment: @Conrad : You are right. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JesseElliott : Thank you for your response. There probably is a mistake in that answer, which is now deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Let me put my comment in an answer since it seems to solve the problem at least in the analytic continuation, poles, residues etc way.

Fix a level $k \ge 1$, then using the asymptotics $H_n=\log n+\gamma + \sum_{1 \le j \le k}c_jn^{-2j} +r_k(n)$ with $r_k(n)=O_k(n^{-2k})$, we can write:

$$F(s)=-\zeta'(s)+\gamma \zeta(s)+ \sum_{1 \le j \le k}c_j\zeta(s+2j)+R_k(s)$$
valid for $\Re s >1$ where $R_k$ is analytic on $\Re s >1-2k$. Hence he RHS above is meromorphic on $\Re s >1-2k$ giving the continuation of $F$ there with poles at $1-2j, j \ge 0$

Unfortunately, the $H_n$ representation is asymptotic only (so not valid as  a series pointwise) since the coefficients $c_k, r_k(n)$ blow up with $k$, so the same happens with the representation of $F$ in the sense that we cannot write it as a series of analytic functions, just an equality at each level $k$ with remainder $R_k$ which is analytic and about which we can find some bounds depending on $k,s$ of course but whose coefficients as a Dirichlet series can be very large in $k$ although of course bounded by $C_kn^{-2k}$ in $n$